# Laravel 5.5 Add validation for multiple attributes

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I have a form that has firstname, middlename and lastname fields. I wanted to validate all three of them so that there will be no identical employee with that record. If it has identical user I wanted it to throw an error into the MessageBag.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the *unique* validation provided by Laravel's validation component, you can also put this code inside your **FormRequest**, instead of this.

> unique:[table_name],[column_name]

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'first_name' => 'unique:employees,first_name',
    'middle_name' => 'unique:employees,middle_name',
    'last_name' => 'unique:employees,last_name'
]);
```

To get the error bag, just use the `withErrors` and pass the `$validator`.

```
return redirect('to.where.it.is')->withErrors($validator);
```

Comment: The problem with that is for example there's an employee named John Doe and your input is John Smith, it will already trigger the errorbag since the first name is not unique. What I want is all three first name, middle name and last name combined to be unique

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41690951/how-to-add-unique-validation-on-combination-of-firstname-and-lastname-in-laravel. Furthermore, I suggest that you have column for the full name, then there you should compare against if an employee with that name already exists.